# I get undefined when I try to get id of last updated row

Tags: mysql, node.js

The below MySQL command was tested on phpmyadmin and worked fine. The command doesn't have any problem. When I try to use it on Node.js I can't get result of the updated id and I get `undefined` on `results` parameter

```
function registerNewAccount(username, password, name, family, mobileNumber, callback) {

    var query = "SET @update_id := 0; UPDATE users SET username = ?, password = ?, name= ?, family = ?, id = (SELECT @update_id := id) WHERE mobileNumber = ?; SELECT @update_id;";
    connection.query(query, [username, password, name, family, mobileNumber] , function (err, results) {
        if (err) return callback(false);

        console.log(results);
    });
}
```

I'm trying to get the id of last updated row with this command. How can I fix that?

Comment: This would appear to have more to do with mysql than JavaScript or Node.js...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to create connection like this : `var connection = mysql.createConnection({multipleStatements: true});`

Comment: could you help me how can i get `@update_id` from this result which it is content of `results` variable?  `[ OkPacket {
    fieldCount: 0,
    affectedRows: 0,
    insertId: 0,
    changedRows: 0 },
  OkPacket {
    fieldCount: 0,
    changedRows: 1 },
  [ RowDataPacket { '@update_id': 29 } ] ]`

Comment: @mahdipishguy You have 3 statements so results is an array with 3 items. In third statement you select `@update_id`, so you can get it like : `results[2]['@update_id']`

Comment: @mahdipishguy The correct one is `results[2][0]['@update_id']`

Comment: Yes, Thank you very much